# Concatenate string and number in batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, concatenation

How to concatenate number and string in for loop?
I've tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
SET PATH=C:\file
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,5) DO (
    SET "NUM=0%%x"
    SET VAR=%PATH%%NUM%
    ECHO %VAR%
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027070/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET PATH=C:\file
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,5) DO (
    SET "NUM=0%%x"
    SET VAR=%PATH%!NUM!
    ECHO !VAR!
)
```

You always have to use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `!...!` instead of `%...%` when working with variables which are modified inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) to accomplish that:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET FILEPATH=C:\file
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,5) DO (
    SET "VAR=%FILEPATH%0%%x"
    ECHO !VAR!
)
ENDLOCAL & SET VAR=%VAR%
```

You do not need the interim variable `NUM`, you can concatenate the string portions immediately.

You should **never** change variable `PATH` as this is used by the system. Hence I changed it to `FILEPATH`.

Since `SETLOCAL` creates a new localised environment block, all variables defined or changed in there cannot be seen outside of that block. However, the last line in the above code demonstrates how the *last* concatenated value can be passed beyond `ENDLOCAL`.