# batch dir output including concatenation to a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a directory which I'd like to output the subfolder names (ex: "folder_1" "folder2" "folder 3") enclosed in single quotes and followed by a comma each, into a txt file.

Based off the solution @ [How to concatenate strings in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2027070/4534651) I managed to come up with the below batch file:

```
@echo off  
set myvar='  
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /o:n /ad') DO  call :concat %%i  
echo %myvar% >>test.txt  
goto :eof   

:concat  
set myvar=%myvar%%1',   
goto :eof
```

which produces a .txt file containing the output:

```
'folder_1', folder2', folder',
```

How can I get the output to look more like this:

```
'folder_1',  
'folder2',  
'folder 3'
```

--Need each subfolder name (incl space/s) enclosed in single quotes followed by comma. If possible, I'd also like each folder on a separate line and no comma on the very last folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with the missing characters, you are missing one thing from your `for` statement.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /o:n /ad') DO  call :concat %%i
```

The `"tokens=*"` part tells `for` to treat the entire line as one variable.  By default, `for` will split each line into separate variables on spaces, which results in you only getting the first word of each line

To fix the single-line issue, you will need to issue multiple `echo` statements.  Right now, your code is collecting everything into one variable and then echoing it as a single line.  Instead, you can append one line to the file each time through the loop, by moving the echo into your `:concat` subroutine.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /o:n /ad') DO  call :concat %%i  
goto :eof   

:concat  
echo '%*', >>test.txt  
goto :eof
```

In the `echo` line, `%*` means "all of the arguments". You can't use `%1` here because, again, CMD splits arguments on spaces.  To learn more about CMD arguments, see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Another way to preserve the spaces is to put quotes around the variable in `call :concat "%%i"`, which prevents CMD from splitting the argument.  In the subfunction, you then use `%~1` instead of `%*`.

Comment: Thank you !! I no longer need the `set myvar='` right? Also, do you know what the purpose of `%%i` is and also the percentage in `echo '%*',`?